# Move from MittelSchule to Realschule

Tags: germany, education

What are the steps to move from MittelSchule to RealSchule in Bavaria?

For a student in class 7th, what are the chances to go to Realschule.

Comment: Probably dependent of the state where you are going to school, since schools are handled by state laws.

Comment: in Munich, Bavaria. I want to know if a kid learns German till B2, is that enough or there are some tests in science or maths?

Answer (score 1):

The best advise that can be given is to talk to the school itsself.

That said, the list (shown below) from the [Bavarian Education Ministry](https://www.km.bayern.de/eltern/schularten/uebertritt-schulartwechsel.html)  states 2 possible combinations for **Mittelschule** -> **Realschule**:

- grade (Note)  average of **2.0** for German, Math and English (for the whole year)
- otherwise: after successful qualification tests

**Note**: German grade system: 1.0 (best) down to 6.0 (worst).

---

> **Übertrittsvoraussetzungen Realschule**
>   **Übertritt in die 7., 8. und 9. Jahrgangsstufe**
>   **Von der Mittelschule**:
>   - **Durchschnittsnote** aus Deutsch, Mathematik, Englisch (Jahreszeugnis) bis 2,0 und bestandene Probezeit: Übertritt möglich (Entscheidung der Eltern nach Beratung).
>   - **In allen anderen Fällen**: Übertritt möglich nach bestandener Aufnahmeprüfung und Probezeit.
>
> > **Transfer requirements secondary school**
> >     **Transition to the 7th, 8th and 9th grade**
> >     **from middle school**:
> >     **- Average grade** from German, mathematics, English (annual certificate) to 2.0 and passed probationary period: transfer possible (decision of the parents after consultation).
> >     **- In all other cases**: transfer possible after passing the entrance exam and trial period.

---

**Sources**:

- [Übertritt und Schulwechsel in Bayern: So geht die Schulkarriere weiter](https://www.km.bayern.de/eltern/schularten/uebertritt-schulartwechsel.html)